# Adding information into new rows in between occupied rows using VBA user form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would need a code to program in adding new rows when there is an empty rows in between occupied rows.

**For example,** there is an empty row between the first and third occupied row.

Thus, i would need a code to program and insert information into the empty row in between the occupied rows using VBA user form.

I managed to create some coding but it seems not to be able to work. I hope anyone could help me.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()

lastrow = Sheets("Programme Status Summary").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(lastrow + 1, "J").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "E").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "C").Value = TextBoxSegment.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "F").Value = TextBoxSummary.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "G").Value = TextBoxAcc1.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "H").Value = TextBoxAcc2.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "I").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "K").Value = TextBoxCountry.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "L").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "M").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "P").Value = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "R").Value = TextBoxSchPar.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "S").Value = TextBoxImpact.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "T").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "U").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "V").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "W").Value = TextBoxListImpt.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "X").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "N").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "O").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "Y").Value = TextBoxRagStatus.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "Z").Value = TextBoxRagCost.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "AA").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! we will need more information to help you with this one. Any information on where are you stuck? What's the error? etc.

Comment: Hi currently the code above does run but it goes to the last row but not rows in between that is empty when i click on the add command button. I would need a code to actually find the empty rows in between rows that are filled but the code above does not seem to work at all. Thus I am a little lost on how to do it.  @Nilesh

Comment: you need to add more details for your question.

Comment: k mind ur own business

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as basis, you'd need to add a loop, to find those line:

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()
dim lngLastRow as Long
dim i as integer
dim wksWork as worksheet

set wksWork = thisworkbook.worksheets("Programme Status Summary")
lngLastRow = wksWork.Range("J" & wksWork.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

for i = 1 to lngLastRow  'This starts in row 1, adjust accordingly
  if wkswork.cells(i,1).value="" or wksWork.cells(i,1).value = vbNullstring then 'Checks in column A if there is any value given
    with wksWork
      .Cells(i, "J").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
      .Cells(i, "E").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
      .Cells(i, "C").Value = TextBoxSegment.Text
      .Cells(i, "F").Value = TextBoxSummary.Text
      .Cells(i, "G").Value = TextBoxAcc1.Text
      .Cells(i, "H").Value = TextBoxAcc2.Text
      .Cells(i, "I").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
      .Cells(i, "K").Value = TextBoxCountry.Text
      .Cells(i, "L").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
      .Cells(i, "M").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
      .Cells(i, "P").Value = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
      .Cells(i, "R").Value = TextBoxSchPar.Text
      .Cells(i, "S").Value = TextBoxImpact.Text
      .Cells(i, "T").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
      .Cells(i, "U").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
      .Cells(i, "V").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
      .Cells(i, "W").Value = TextBoxListImpt.Text
      .Cells(i, "X").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
      .Cells(i, "N").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
      .Cells(i, "O").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
      .Cells(i, "Y").Value = TextBoxRagStatus.Text
      .Cells(i, "Z").Value = TextBoxRagCost.Text
      .Cells(i, "AA").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
    end with
  end if
next i
End Sub
```

Comment: alright thank you! i will give it a try and let you know the outcome of it! :) @Blind Seer